# Bayesian Hypothesis Testing after Frequentist Parameter Estimation

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, frequentist

Is it sound to use a Bayesian hypothesis testing framework after a frequentist parameter estimation (via the implied distribution by the estimated parameters)?

Comment: Could you add more details? It is unclear what kind of testing it is, and how the parameter in question (and its estimate) appear in the Bayesian test.

Comment: Mixing both approaches is not usually recommended!